# Prevent a user from going to any other URL

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2, kiosk

I am presently working on a **Raspberry Pi 2** running **Raspbian Jessie** membership registration kiosk our tech work-space. I have worked out most of the issues such as closing the browser, right-clicking, keyboard shortcuts, and secure login for admins.

The problem I've run into is that the website, that is not under my control, has links to outside websites that I don't want our users going to check the present URL make sure that it is the one approved URL and redirect if it isn't. I've researched doing this with **software** such as **Privoxy** and **squid** and also **Python** but so far haven't found anything that works. I am very new to **Python** though it seems the most likely solution, **Privoxy** just doesn't work, and it seems **Squid** really wasn't meant for what I'm trying to do.

The overall goal is to ensure a good, consistent interaction between the users and the kiosk so that we're not having to constantly reset the device and field questions like, "why doesn't it work?"

I'll keep searching and post anything that I find but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to create your own web browser application.  You can do this with [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef), which allows you to embed Chrome inside your application with only a few lines of code.  CEF has Python bindings, if that's your preferred language.  In order to restrict navigation, you would create a custom [`RequestHandler` subclass](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/wiki/RequestHandler) and write an `OnBeforeBrowse()` function that prevents the user from navigating to external sites.  Control is fairly fine-grained, so you can write different rules for handling iframe versus main window navigation.

You may also want to look at the [LifespanHandler](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/wiki/LifespanHandler), which handles pop-up windows.

Be careful about purging data between user sessions, an easy way to do this is to terminate the application and restart it.